# How to merge these tiny faces?

Tags: modeling, faces, topology

I have these messy tiny faces that I want merge them into nice smooth faces just like other parts of the object. What would be the best way to do this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the *Decimate* modifier in the *Collapse* mode, then adjust the *Ratio* property as desired.

[image]

Bad topology and occasional glitches are to be expected, you may have to do additional cleanup by hand. You can also try the *Remesh* modifier if you wish to retopologise.